# Generate Pie Charts with Force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, force-layout

My intention is generate physics between svg boxes and pies charts

I start with this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852

can I add collisions like this pie from this site: http://social.ufc.com/?

Any example or recomendation?

Comment: You'll want to look at the [clustered force layout examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887) to arrange your nodes; but then for each one, instead of the node being a `<circle>`, you make it a `<g>` element and then draw your pie chart inside.

Comment: Great.  Do you want to write up a quick answer to help anyone trying to do something similar in the future?

Comment: yes of course, but i need learn so much and more practice before help other people's.